# Посчитать сумму промежутков -ORACLE

Tags: oracle

Как составить запрос в оракле, что бы посчитать сумму промежутков, количества дней у ID  между проводимыми операциями?
Формат данных следующий.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Промежутками будет являться даты между 0 "Входящего остатка" и 0 "Исходящего остатка".

Comment: Покажите желаемый результат на показанных данных. А вообще тупо школьная задачка на LEAD/LAG и CASE.

Comment: Результат "33"  дня в общем, округление в большую сторону. Можете примером показать?

Comment: *округление в большую сторону.* Не понял??? какое округление? чего именно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Схематически

```
SELECT SUM(   TO_DATE(datetime, 
                      'DD.MM.YYYY HH:MI:SS')
            - TO_DATE(LAG(datetime) OVER (ORDER BY datetime ASC), 
                      'DD.MM.YYYY HH:MI:SS')
          ) AS TOTAL_DIFFERENCE
FROM tablename
WHERE outcome_reminder = 0 -- плюс, возможно, ещё проверки
```

Запрос предполагает, что данные именно такие - при сортировке по дате вход-выход строго чередуются. Иначе требуется подготовка данных и деление на "пары". А если учёт сумм накопительный - то совсем становится нетривиально...

PS. С синтаксисом мог и накосячить - требует проверки.

Comment: Считает не правильно. Подзапросом вытащил правильные ответы. Благодарю.

Comment: можете еще показать как выполнить подготовку данных и деление на пары? Например в случае если есть еще значения между датами?

Comment: @AndreyZhuravlev Подготовьте набор скриптов создания (CREATE TABLE) и наполнения (INSERT INTO) таблицы с различными вариантами - тогда для них можно будет верстать способы решения. PS. Полагаю, разумнее это будет сделать в новом вопросе. Возможно, дав ссылку на этот...