# Посчитать сумму промежутков 2 -ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

Как составить запрос в оракле, что бы посчитать сумму промежутков, количества дней у ID между проводимыми операциями? Формат данных следующий.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Промежутками будет являться даты между 0 "Входящего остатка" и 0 "Исходящего остатка".

В предыдущем [вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/967714/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-oracle) не учел возможность того что проводок может быть несколько.Как можно посчитать такие данные? Что я делаю не так, для того что бы посчитать сумму всех промежутков?

```
--begin executor.set_system_context(true);end;
SELECT a.C_1 "ID"
      ,a.C_4 "Наименование"
    --,MAX(TO_DATE(b.C_1))-MIN(TO_DATE(b.C_1)) as timerrr
      ,SUM(LAG(TO_DATE(b.C_1)) OVER (PARTITION BY  ORDER BY b.C_1 ASC )- 
       TO_DATE(b.C_1)) as SUMM  
FROM    
(SELECT /*+ FIRST_ROWS */ *
 FROM IBS.VW_CRIT_AC_FIN 
 WHERE C_1 IN('4488','4489') ) a
     LEFT JOIN (SELECT /*+ FIRST_ROWS */ *
                FROM IBS.VW_CRIT_FULL_RECORDS WHERE (C_1 >= 
                TO_DATE('01/01/2018','DD/MM/YYYY') and C_1 < 
                TO_DATE('08/04/2019', 'DD/MM/YYYY') + 1) AND ( C_4 = 0.00 OR C_9 
                 = 0.00) ) b ON a.REF13=b.COLLECTION_ID
                WHERE b.C_9=0
GROUP BY
 a.C_1 
,a.C_4 
,b.C_1
```

Comment: `WITH cte AS (SELECT * FROM datatable WHERE in=0 OR out=0)`, а далее как по ссылке...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так нужно, как я понимаю:

```
select max(datetime) - min(datetime) days_count, group_id
  from (select datetime, 
               sum(case when rest_in = 0 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by datetime) group_id
          from table)
group by group_id
```

Здесь `rest_in` - входящий остаток, когда он ноль, ставим 1, когда не ноль - ставим ноль, а потом считаем сумму с накоплением. Получается, что напротив каждого периода стоит его номер (`group_id`). Ну а дальше все просто: для каждого периода вычитаем его минимум из максимума.

Comment: столкнулся со следующей проблемой. Если брать несколько значений для подсчета, то данный скрипт неправильно считает. Ставит 0. Разобрал поглубже, когда происходит группировка то одна из дат исчезает. остается только одна из группы(нпример 2). В чем может быть проблема? Если брать индивидуально то все  корректно.

Comment: Дайте исходные данные. Желательно в текстовом виде в скрипте. Типа такого: `with t as (select 123 from dual union all ... ` и т. д.