# Как правильно использовать WITH? - Oracle

Tags: oracle

При использовании в  коде строки(взято из ответа от [сюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/967798/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-2-oracle)):

```
SUM(CASE WHEN INe =0 then 1 else 0 end )  over (order by DateL) group_id
```

, образуется несколько одинаковых значений в группировке, если использовать больше одного условия в WITH, что приводит к некорректному конечному значению при подсчете суммы разницы во времени.
Как этого избежать?

```
with T AS ( select '20003061' AS Number1 from dual union
            select '2000423' from dual union
            select '2003134' from dual )
, T2 as( SELECT SHET
               ,CEIL(SUM(days_count)) SUMM_DAY
         FROM ( SELECT Shet
                      ,MAX(DateL) - MIN(DateL) days_count     
                FROM ( SELECT DateL,
                              Shet,
                              SUM(CASE WHEN INe =0 
                                       then 1 
                                       else 0 end )  over (order by DateL) group_id    
                       FROM ( SELECT a.C_1 Shet
                                    ,a.C_4 Nms
                                    ,b.C_4 INe
                                    ,b.C_9 OUTe
                                    ,b.C_1 DateL
                                    ,(LAG(b.C_1) OVER (ORDER BY b.C_1 ASC)-b.C_1) AS DIFFF
                              FROM T  
                              LEFT JOIN IBS.VW_CRIT_AC_FIN  a ON T.Number1 = a.C_1
                              LEFT JOIN ( SELECT /*+ FIRST_ROWS */ *
                                          FROM IBS.VW_CRIT_FULL_RECORDS 
                                          WHERE (     C_1 >= TO_DATE('01/01/2018', 'DD/MM/YYYY') 
                                                  and C_1 < TO_DATE('08/04/2019', 'DD/MM/YYYY') + 1) 
                                        ) b ON a.REF13=b.COLLECTION_ID
                            )
                     )
               GROUP BY group_id,Shet
              )
         GROUP BY SHET
       )
Select T2.* FROM T2
```

Comment: With по сути возвращает вам таблицу. Наверное у вас проблема не в With, а в том, как вы формируете условия. Но пока вы не объясните что не так, как правильно и так далее, это выглядит как гадание по фотографии. Прочитайте о том, как создать [минимальный и самодостаточный пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Viktorov, перефразировал вопрос.

Comment: А какие данные у Вас в таблице IBS.VW_CRIT_FULL_RECORDS? Приведите работающий пример с данными, пожалуйста.